# How can I easily get the previous results of my searchbar input when I push the back button of the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Do I have to use a localstorage and do I have to add it to my searchbar code?

```
    const filteredOrganizations = context.allOrganizations.filter(organization => {
        const searchTerms = organization.topic.searchTerms.map(term => term.toLowerCase()).join(" ");
        const organizationName = organization.name.toLowerCase();
        const searchString = `${searchTerms} ${organizationName}`;

        return searchString.includes(searchText.toLowerCase());
    });
```

tried it with javascript:history.back(), but it could not have shown me my previous results